# Customized Kml with ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, kml, fields-attributes, duplication

I'm using ArcGIS 10 desktop version. I need to customize my kml files as to what they pop up in Google Earth. One of the attributes appears twice even when the field is not enabled.

[image]

The picture repeats the head in the first row which is not required. Since the points are too many, I cannot manually eliminate all the heads. The following picture indicates the same issue, none of the fields have been enabled yet the name appears twice. Can anyone help me avoid repetition.

[image: l]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open layer's properties and choose HTML Poup.
Tick "Use the scheme of XML".

Choose "upload the template" and find popup.xsl (C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.2\Styles\HTMLPopup)
After delete line:

```
    </head>
        <body style="margin:0px 0px 0px 0px;overflow:auto;background:#FFFFFF;">
            <table style="font-family:Arial,Verdana,Times;font-size:12px;text-align:left;width:100%;border-collapse:collapse;padding:3px 3px 3px 3px">
                <tr style="text-align:center;font-weight:bold;background:{$headerRowColor}">
                    <td>    
                        <xsl:value-of select="FieldsDoc/Title" /> **delete only this line
                    </td>
                </tr>
```

Before

[image: Before]

After

[image: After]

**UPDATE**
Add your kml layer as new layer. In propeties of HTML poup
insert next code in window of XSL. (IF you insert in exist layers, it will not help)

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt">
    <xsl:variable name="ignoreFieldNames" select="'|OBJECTID|Shape|Shape_Length|Shape_Area|ATTACHMENTID|REL_OBJECTID|CONTENT_TYPE|ATT_NAME|DATA_SIZE|DATA|'"/>
    <xsl:variable name="headerRowColor" select="'#9CBCE2'"/>
    <xsl:variable name="alternateRowColor" select="'#D4E4F3'"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <head>
                <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
            </head>
            <body style="margin:0px 0px 0px 0px;overflow:auto;background:#FFFFFF;">
                <table style="font-family:Arial,Verdana,Times;font-size:12px;text-align:left;width:100%;border-collapse:collapse;padding:3px 3px 3px 3px">
                    <tr style="text-align:center;font-weight:bold;background:{$headerRowColor}">
                        <td>

                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="FieldsDoc/Attachments" />
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <table style="font-family:Arial,Verdana,Times;font-size:12px;text-align:left;width:100%;border-spacing:0px; padding:3px 3px 3px 3px">
                                <xsl:choose>
                                    <xsl:when test="FieldsDoc/Fields/Field/FieldName">
                                        <xsl:apply-templates select="FieldsDoc/Fields/Field/FieldName[not(contains($ignoreFieldNames, concat(concat('|', text()), '|')))]/.." />
                                    </xsl:when>
                                    <xsl:otherwise>
                                        <xsl:apply-templates select="FieldsDoc/Fields/Field" />
                                    </xsl:otherwise>
                                </xsl:choose>
                            </table>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Attachments">
        <xsl:variable name="imageCount" select="count(Attachment/ContentType[contains(., 'image')])"/>
        <xsl:variable name="attachmentCount" select="count(Attachment)"/>
        <tr bgcolor="{$headerRowColor}">
            <td>
                <table style="font-family:Arial,Verdana,Times;font-size:12px;text-align:left;width:100%;border-spacing:0px; padding:3px 3px 3px 3px">
                    <xsl:variable name="imageSrc" select="Attachment/ContentType[contains(., 'image')]/../FilePath"/>
                    <xsl:if test="$imageSrc">
                        <tr align="center">
                            <td>
                                <a target="_blank" href="{$imageSrc}">
                                    <img src="{$imageSrc}" width="275px" border="0"/>
                                </a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr align="center">
                            <td>
                                <xsl:value-of select="Attachment/ContentType[contains(., 'image')]/../Name" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </xsl:if>
                    <xsl:if test="($attachmentCount &gt; $imageCount) or not($imageCount = 1)">
                        <tr align="center">
                            <td>
                                <table style="font-family:Arial,Verdana,Times;font-size:12px;text-align:left;width:100%;border-spacing:0px; padding:3px 3px 3px 3px">
                                    <xsl:for-each select="Attachment[position() mod 2 = 1]">
                                        <tr align="left" bgcolor="white">
                                            <xsl:if test="(position() +1) mod 2">
                                                <xsl:attribute name="bgcolor">
                                                    <xsl:value-of select="$alternateRowColor"/>
                                                </xsl:attribute>
                                            </xsl:if>
                                            <td>
                                                <a target="_blank">
                                                    <xsl:attribute name="href">
                                                        <xsl:value-of select="FilePath"/>
                                                    </xsl:attribute>
                                                    <xsl:value-of select="Name" />
                                                </a>
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                <a target="_blank">
                                                    <xsl:attribute name="href">
                                                        <xsl:value-of select="following-sibling::Attachment/FilePath"/>
                                                    </xsl:attribute>
                                                    <xsl:value-of select="following-sibling::Attachment/Name" />
                                                </a>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </xsl:for-each>
                                </table>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </xsl:if>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Field">
        <tr>
            <xsl:if test="(position() +1) mod 2">
                <xsl:attribute name="bgcolor">
                    <xsl:value-of select="$alternateRowColor"/>
                </xsl:attribute>
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:if test="FieldName">
                <td>
                    <xsl:value-of select="FieldName"/>
                </td>
            </xsl:if>
            <td>
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="FieldValue[starts-with(., 'www.')]">
                        <a target="_blank">
                            <xsl:attribute name="href">http://<xsl:value-of select="FieldValue"/>
                            </xsl:attribute>
                            <xsl:value-of select="FieldValue"/>
                        </a>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:when test="FieldValue[starts-with(., 'http:')]">
                        <a target="_blank">
                            <xsl:attribute name="href">
                                <xsl:value-of select="FieldValue"/>
                            </xsl:attribute>
                            <xsl:value-of select="FieldValue"/>
                        </a>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:when test="FieldValue[starts-with(., 'https:')]">
                        <a target="_blank">
                            <xsl:attribute name="href">
                                <xsl:value-of select="FieldValue"/>
                            </xsl:attribute>
                            <xsl:value-of select="FieldValue"/>
                        </a>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:when test="FieldValue[starts-with(., '\\')]">
                        <a target="_blank">
                            <xsl:attribute name="href">
                                <xsl:value-of select="FieldValue"/>
                            </xsl:attribute>
                            <xsl:value-of select="FieldValue"/>
                        </a>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:when test="FieldValue[starts-with(., '&lt;img ')]">
                        <xsl:value-of select="FieldValue" disable-output-escaping="yes" />
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                        <xsl:value-of select="FieldValue"/>
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I'm using version 10 here, in plae of 10.1 and HTML Popup tab appears to have different options... Anyways, I could reach the said address, but deletion ain't occurring, I have all the rights though!

Comment: I hope this working in any v 10.** Update answer

Comment: OK, I messed up somewhere... I pasted the given code (above, smaller in content) and now nothing pops up at all. I lost the already written line of code as well... can I get the whole content of htmlpopup.xsl

Comment: The last code this is the whole content of document xsl. You can open notepad (or similar) insert last code and save as htmlpopup.xsl. **Code above** is describes what to change. **Last code** ready to work))

Comment: that's cool... its just that a line appears after head or the first line... how can I remove the line as well...

Comment: **The element <tr>** serves as a container to create a string table. Each cell within a row set using the <th> elements or <td>. **<td>** is intended to create a single table cell. <td> elements must be placed inside the container <tr>, which in turn is located within the <table>.

Comment: this is about elements http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_table_test